# Getting records with no matching records in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the below 2 tables MySQL database.

```
CREATE TABLE `leads` (
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_mobile` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `leads`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`lead_id`);

ALTER TABLE `leads`
  MODIFY `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

CREATE TABLE `card_results` (
  `card_result_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `success` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `card_results`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`card_result_id`),
  ADD KEY `created` (`created`),
  ADD KEY `success` (`success`);

ALTER TABLE `card_results`
  MODIFY `card_result_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `card_results`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_card_results_lead_id` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_id`) REFERENCES `leads` (`lead_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
COMMIT;
```

I wish to find all records in the `leads` table where there are no matching records in the `card_results` table in the last 3 months.

The 2 tables are related by the foreign key 'lead_id'

My query is below:

```
SELECT l.lead_id
FROM leads l
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM card_results c
     WHERE success = 1
       AND created >= NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH
       AND c.lead_id = l.lead_id) = 0
```

The query runs a little slow and I would like to optimise it.

Is there another way to achieve the same result.

Comment: why don't you use `join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY in one of the following ways:

Using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT l.lead_id
FROM leads l
WHERE l.lead_id NOT IN (
    SELECT c.lead_id 
    FROM card_results c
    WHERE success = 1
    AND created >= NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Using `JOIN` and `IS NULL`

```
SELECT l.lead_id
FROM leads l
LEFT JOIN card_results c ON c.lead_id = l.lead_id
    AND c.success = 1
    AND created >= NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH
WHERE c.lead_id IS NULL
```

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT l.lead_id
FROM leads l
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
     FROM card_results c
     WHERE success = 1
       AND created >= NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH
       AND c.lead_id = l.lead_id)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used Not In

Answer (score 2):

You could use `LEFT` join with `IS NULL` make sure your filters should be used in `ON` clause rather than `WHERE`

```
SELECT l.lead_id
FROM leads l
LEFT JOIN card_results c 
       ON l.lead_id = c.lead_id
       AND c.created >= NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH
       AND c.success = 1
WHERE c.lead_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Exactly what I'd do too. Always use joins before subqueries. Much easier to read and easier to optimize with hints, complies with set theory.